# Enabling the Content-Security-Policy header for all REST calls via XML

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

I've been asked to set the `Content-Security-Policy` headers on **all** responses to a REST API with out having to configure them individually.

The interface itself is secured by saml and my efforts to add a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class have had the unfortunate effect of interfering with the spring-security-saml2-core library. (The result was that the configure method of my Configurer was never being called). Since this library is effectively a black box I'd prefer to leave it alone

The only alternative I'd can see is to use XML configuration to add the headers. But how?

I'm seeing lots of documentation that suggests adding:

```
<http>
  <!-- ... -->

  <headers>
    <content-security-policy policy-directives="script-src 'self'" />
  </headers>
</http>
```

but to where? I know `http` is part of the Spring security name space, but headers doesn't appear to be a valid child element as I get the error:

```
ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 35 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 35; columnNumber: 13; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'headers'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":intercept-url, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":access-denied-handler, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":form-login, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":openid-login, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":x509, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":jee, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":http-basic, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":logout, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":session-management, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":remember-me, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":anonymous, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":port-mappings, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":custom-filter, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":request-cache, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":expression-handler, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":headers, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":csrf, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":cors}' is expected.
```

Comment: any luck on fixing the issue?

Comment: @tk_ no luck. I gave up in the end. If you ever find out how I'd still be interested

Answer (score 1):

You can try like:

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="">
<security:headers>
     <security:content-security-policy policy-directives="default-src 'self'"/>
</security:headers>
</security:http>
```

Comment: this is throwing not found error. any help pls?